# Is the QGIS 3.10 "fix geometries" batch-processing interface missing a parameter?

Tags: qgis

My goal is to write five features classes from one FGDB to five tables in one GeoPackage using QGIS 3.10 (Dutch version). I'm trying to do this using the QGIS function fix geometries (Dutch "geometrieën repareren).
If I 'fix' one feature class at a time, everything is fine. But when I try to run the fix geometries function as a batch process through the QGIS user interface (see attached image), QGIS tries to write five GeoPackages with the same name. The name of the output Geopackages can be set as a parameter (GeoPackageInputlayer), but my goal is to write all the output of this batch in to the same GeoPackage. This option isn't supported in the user interface.

Is there a way to write the five tables into one GeoPackage using the GQIS batch process interface of the FixGeometries function?

This is the input for the batch processing of the function 'fix geometries':
[image: Input for batch processing 'fix geometries']

And this is the error (file already exists):
[image]

Comment: I'm going off of memory so it might not work, but if you select the autofill drop down and choose calculate by expression and then double click on output to make it your expression, does that work?

Comment: You might want to change your "answer" to a comment to encourage other readers to find you a good answer or edit your original question to show your goal.  I don't have a good answer just an off the cuff suggestion.  You might try concatenating the input to the output?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Johns. I've tried that option before posting my question here. The result in my case: five GeoPackages with a name like 'GeoPackageInputlayername.gpkg.' 
My goal is to have one GeoPackage with five tables as a result of this batch process.